# Visual Blend Annimating Image Background

Tags: c#, xaml, background, blend

[image: Image from https://www.flickr.com/photos/markusspiske/14201997467/in/album-72157645103340985/ free for commercial use]

If the user starts the app there should be a annimated background. The Background of the Maingrid is that picture above. The background should be moved. How can I do this in Visual Blend? I'm aware of how to create annimations in blend but I don't know how to do this kind of annimation.

Comment: If I set the stretch property to fill the picture doesnt fill the screen during the annimation and also not after the annimation

Comment: Don't really understand the comments on your picture, you just want the image to move slightly on the background right?

Comment: The Background should move for example to the right so that the backround is moving and showing different parts of the picture

Comment: So the background just needs to move from the where the "OLD" red box is, to where the "NEW" red box is but in the same area? Sorry, hard to visualize what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something along the lines of this:

```
<Canvas.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">

    <!-- The PointAnimation has a name so it can be accessed
         from code. The To property is left out of the XAML
         because the value of To is determined in code. -->
    <PointAnimation
      x:Name="clockAnimation"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center"
      Storyboard.TargetName="clockImage"
      Duration="0:0:20"/>
  </Storyboard>
</Canvas.Resources>
```

And this C# which can be done on a timer or on initialisation:

```
double newX = 'Where you want the new X coordinate of the clock';
double newY = 'Where you want the new Y coordinate of the clock';
Point myPoint = new Point();
myPoint.X = newX;
myPoint.Y = newY;
clockAnimation.To = myPoint;
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do (as i understand it) is impossible **without** modifying the image you've shown fundamentally.

From the sounds of it what you're looking to do is animate the hands in this *static* two-dimensional image. You can no more move the hands on the clock of this static image as you could if you were to print it out onto a sheet of paper and attempt the same.

One solution would be to use an image-editing tool such as photoshop to erase the hands in question leaving you with  an empty clock-face.
From there you can use it as the background as you intend, but create assets on the layer(s) above the now modified image that replicate what the old clock-hands used to look like and animate *them* accordingly.

*(For example; something that should be as simple as making 3 separate animations that have each hand turn 360 degrees, only with the second-hand's animation taking 60seconds to complete, the minute-hand taking 1hour to complete and of course the hour hand taking 12hours to complete its spin (but you said you're competent with animation so i'll leave this part to you).)*